# How to convert image file like jpeg or png to svg file in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert jpg file to svg file in c# .net.

Answer (score 5):

SVG files are vector graphic files, JPG files are raster files. I would say that there is no easy way to automatically convert on to another in C# or another language.

There are several pieces of software that do that - [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_to_vector_conversion_software) is a list on wikipedia.